# Finding number of occurrences in string

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have random data (names) in strings that I need to compare. Data (names) will not always be the same but it will be in this format.

For example, I have two NSString like this:

```
NSString *string1= @"Jordan Mike Liam Taylor Jill Gordon Phil Mark";

NSString *string2= @"Marcus Tony Taylor Anny Keenan Brittany Gordon Mike";
```

Based on these 2 strings, we can see that both strings contain **Mike| Taylor | Gordon**

So the count of same data between these two strings is 3. However I am not able to get it work via code.
The following below is what I have thus far. I feel that I am close but not quite there and would really appreciated some help from the community. Thank you in advance!

```
NSMutableArray *tempArray= [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[tempArray addObject:string1];
[tempArray addObject:string2];

NSCountedSet *bag = [[NSCountedSet alloc] initWithArray:tempArray];

NSString *mostOccurring;
NSUInteger highest = 0;
for (NSString *s in bag)
{
    if ([bag countForObject:s] > highest)
    {
        highest = [bag countForObject:s];
        mostOccurring = s;
    }
}
NSLog(@"Most frequent string: %d", highest);
```

**EDIT CODE**

```
NSUInteger highest = 1;
NSUInteger theCount=0;
for (NSString *s in bag)
{
    if ([bag countForObject:s] > highest)
    {
        highest = [bag countForObject:s];
        mostOccurring = s;

    }
if (highest ==2)
{
    theCount++;
}

}
NSLog(@"Most frequent string: %d", theCount);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am late to answer this question, but have a look here :

```
NSString *string1= @"Jordan Mike Liam Taylor Jill Gordon Phil Mark a";
NSString *string2= @"Marcus Tony Taylor Anny Keenan Brittany Gordon Mike";
NSMutableSet *set1=[NSMutableSet setWithArray:[string1 componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]];
NSMutableSet *set2=[NSMutableSet setWithArray:[string2 componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]];
[set1 intersectSet:set2];

NSArray *intersect=[set1 allObjects];//intersect contains all the common elements

NSLog(@"Common count is  %ld.",[intersect count]);
```

Comment: This is a much cleaner solution

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to change your code example very much at all to achieve what you want:

```
    NSString *string1= @"Jordan Mike Liam Taylor Jill Gordon Phil Mark";
    NSString *string2= @"Marcus Tony Taylor Anny Keenan Brittany Gordon Mike";

    NSMutableArray *tempArray= [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [tempArray addObjectsFromArray:[string1 componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]];
    [tempArray addObjectsFromArray:[string2 componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]];

    NSCountedSet *bag = [[NSCountedSet alloc] initWithArray:tempArray];


    NSUInteger repeats = 0;
    NSMutableArray *matches = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSString *s in bag)
    {
        if ([bag countForObject:s] > 1)
        {
            repeats++;
            [matches addObject:s];
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"Number of names repeated: %ld", repeats);
    NSLog(@"Matches: %@", matches);
```

Comment: Thanks for the example Andrew. I took the code snippet above exactly as you have it and changed the NSLog to %d, highest. But I only got the count to be 2 when it should be 3 ( 3 name matches). Any suggestions thank you so much

Comment: If you need to differentiate copies of a name in the same array (e.g. array1 = "Mike Mike"), you should make the temporary arrays (array1 and array2) into sets, and then add them to the counted set.